# typescriptt "\\" not working, how i can use one backslash?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a little problem on Typescript,
How i can use only one backslash ?

I want an url like that : `"\/hello\/"+ urlRoute + "\/([0-9]*)"`,

When I do this I have only `"/hello/"+ urlRoute + "/([0-9]*)"`

But if I do this `"\\/hello\\/"+ urlRoute + "\\/([0-9]*)"`,

the string is `"\\/hello\\/"+ urlRoute + "\\/([0-9]*)"`,

I tried somes solution but didn't work I have always Two/three backslash but never one ^^

If someone can help me,
Thanks

Comment: your second solution works for me

Comment: You only See the Double Backslash in the Debugger, because the debugger formats the string as a string literal. The actual value does not have double backslashes.

Comment: Have you tried `"\\\/hello\\\/"+ urlRoute + "\\\/([0-9]*)"` ?

Comment: With the second solution even with Json.stringify i see the double backslash ...

I tried "\\\" also but i see three backslash

Comment: Ok with console.log I have "\/" but when I JSON.stringify the string the result is "\\/"'

How i can fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

Protip use template strings : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/template-strings.html

That said your code works fine e.g.

```
let urlRoute = "something"; 
console.log("\/hello\/"+ urlRoute + "\/([0-9]*)" == `/hello/something/([0-9]*)`); // prints true
```